# Kubernetes Configuration Management

Tags: kubernetes, configuration-managment

how to inject the configuration shell script in to a running container in kubernetes?
I have a docker image in private docker registry which i have spun on to couple of pods using the yaml as follows:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: c7-sentinel
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      service: sentinel
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: sentinel
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - name: sentinel
        image: docker-hub-dev.blueally.com/c7-sentinel12:1.0.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: my-secret    
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7473
          hostPort: 7473        
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: sentinel
```

Now i want to inject some config files which are as a script as below:

```
`docker_live_image=c7-sentinel16
docker_live_version=1.0.0.0
privatehub=docker-hub-dev.blueally.com
hubuid=bachdocker
hubpwd=Li0nIa2020
sentinel_hostname=docker-brownbag
sentinel_name=docker-brownbag
sentinel_IP=
jwt_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTYiLCJhdWQiOiJUZXN0Q3VzdG9tZXIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTIzOTQ3MjUsImlzcyI6InNhZmVndWFyZC5ibHVlYWxseS5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1NTI1Njc1MjV9.TArK55dODZ_eW5kmuxdVFDsaHWcSwg8ceaxLGvcFPIG9Buzs_43bIJ_NSHtZbhzyhmYXo193UsUDYqYlvjnd1g
registration_key=1WOhY9p7rFBO7YpXeeOjh5AqTDzlctph
security_key=123456
customer_name="Customer1"
gateway_url=https://bach-gw002.blueally.com:8080
rest_api_url=https://safeguard.blueally.com/sentry
rest_api_url_show=`echo "$rest_api_url" | awk -F/ '{ print $1$3 }'| sed 's#:#://#g' `
gateway_urls=https://bach-gw002.blueally.com:8080
gateway_url_show=`echo "$gateway_url" | awk -F: '{ print $1":"$2}'`

updateHostentry () {
docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c '/usr/bin/echo "49.249.253.256   bach-gw002.blueally.com bach-gw002" >> /etc/hosts'
docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c '/usr/bin/echo "182.72.201.256  bach-gw001.blueally.com bach-gw001" >> /etc/hosts'
docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c '/usr/bin/echo "10.4.1.256    sg-dev.blueally.com  sg-dev" >> /etc/hosts'
}


mapports="-p 85:22 -p 514:514 -p 514:514/udp -p 1514:1514 -p 1514:1514/udp -p 162:162 -p 2055:2055 -p 2055:2055/udp -p 6343:6343 -p 6343:6343/udp -p 6344:6344 -p 6344:6344/udp -p 6514:6514 -p 6514:6514/udp -p 45000:45000/udp  -p 30:25 -p 7473:7473"

# echo "Pull docker image from HUB"
# docker pull $privatehub/$docker_live_image:$docker_live_version

echo "Initializing Sentinel image....."

docker run -h $sentinel_hostname -d $mapports -v /data/$sentinel_name/nifi/config/dmidecode:/usr/sbin/dmidecode -v /data/$sentinel_name/nifi/logs:/opt/nifi/logs -v /data/$sentinel_name/nifi/flowfile_repository:/opt/nifi/flowfile_repository -v /data/$sentinel_name/nifi/database_repository:/opt/nifi/database_repository -v /data/$sentinel_name/nifi/content_repository:/opt/nifi/content_repository -v /data/$sentinel_name/nifi/provenance_repository:/opt/nifi/provenance_repository -v /data/$sentinel_name/VulnWhisperer/data:/opt/VulnWhisperer/data --name $sentinel_name -it --restart always $privatehub/$docker_live_image:$docker_live_version
#updated uuid in flow.xml and gzip the file

myuuid=$(dmidecode | grep UUID | awk -F": " '{print $2}')

## echo "Proposed UUID $myuuid"
#echo ' echo "   UUID:  '${myuuid}'"' > /data/$sentinel_name/nifi/config/dmidecode

## REST_END_POINT_URL
PORTAL_SCAN_URL=${rest_api_url}/api/v1/nifi/sentinel/$myuuid
# echo ${PORTAL_SCAN_URL}
PORTAL_SCAN_URL=${rest_api_url_show}

docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c 'mkdir /opt/VulnWhisperer/data/nessus; mkdir /opt/VulnWhisperer/data/openvas; mkdir /opt/VulnWhisperer/data/database; mkdir "/opt/VulnWhisperer/data/nessus/My Scans";'

docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c 'cd /opt/nifi/conf && /usr/bin/gunzip flow.xml.gz && sed -i "s#value=\"PORTAL_SCAN_URL\"#value=\"'${PORTAL_SCAN_URL}'\"#g" /opt/nifi/conf/flow.xml && /usr/bin/gzip flow.xml'
docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c 'cd /opt/nifi/conf && /usr/bin/gunzip flow.xml.gz && sed -i "s#value=\"MYSENTINELUUID\"#value=\"'${myuuid}'\"#g" /opt/nifi/conf/flow.xml && /usr/bin/gzip flow.xml'


docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c 'cd /opt/nifi/conf && /usr/bin/gunzip flow.xml.gz && sed -i "s#<value>ED4707F3-361D-9130-7B33-93853D25A132</value>#<value>"'$myuuid'"</value>#g" /opt/nifi/conf/flow.xml && /usr/bin/gzip flow.xml'

# Updating GatewayUrls
docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c 'cd /opt/nifi/conf && /usr/bin/gunzip flow.xml.gz && sed -i "s#<url>\$GATEWAY_URL\$</url>#<url>"'$gateway_url/nifi'"</url>#" /opt/nifi/conf/flow.xml && sed -i "s#<urls>\$GATEWAY_URLS\$</urls>#<urls>"'$gateway_urls'"</urls>#" /opt/nifi/conf/flow.xml && /usr/bin/gzip flow.xml'

#update sentienl name in nifi.properties
docker exec -it $sentinel_name sed -i 's#nifi.ui.banner.text=.*#nifi.ui.banner.text='$sentinel_name'#' /opt/nifi/conf/nifi.properties

# Function to update hostentry
updateHostentry

# Restart nifi
docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c 'cd /opt/nifi/bin && ./nifi.sh stop && sleep 10 && ./nifi.sh start' >/dev/null
#docker exec -it $sentinel_name bash -c 'cd /opt/nifi/bin && ./nifi.sh status &'



# Updating the sentinel process check
cp -f ${SCRIPTDIR}/sentineld /data/
chmod 755 /data/sentineld
# make cron entry
dt=`date +%d-%m-%Y_%H_%m_%S`
isCronentry=`crontab -l 2> /dev/null | grep -i sentineld |grep -v grep | wc -l`
if [ "${isCronentry}" == "0" ]; then
        crontab -l > /var/log/cron_${dt}.bkp 2> /dev/null
        crontab -l > /tmp/a.cron 2> /dev/null
        echo "*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /data/sentineld check > /tmp/sentineld.check.out" >> /tmp/a.cron
        crontab /tmp/a.cron 2> /dev/null
        rm -f /tmp/a.cron
else
        crontab -l > /var/log/cron_${dt}.bkp 2> /dev/null
        crontab -l | grep -v sentineld > /tmp/a.cron 2> /dev/null
        echo "*/15 * * * * /bin/sh /data/sentineld check > /tmp/sentineld.check.out" >> /tmp/a.cron
        crontab /tmp/a.cron 2> /dev/null
        rm -f /tmp/a.cron
fi


## sentinel_IP=`hostname -i | awk '{print $1 }'`
## sentinel_IP=`hostname -i 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $1 }'`
        sentinel_IP=`ip a | grep -w "inet" | grep -v 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d"/" -f1 | head -1`
if [ "$sentinel_IP"  == "" ] ; then
        sentinel_IP=`hostname -iI 2> /dev/null | awk '{print $1 }'`
fi

        dkr_sentinel_IP=`docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $sentinel_name`
if [ "$dkr_sentinel_IP"  == "" ] ; then
        dkr_sentinel_IP=`docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' $sentinel_name`
fi

SIEMDIR="/data"
if [ ! -d "$SIEMDIR" ]; then
        mkdir /data 2> /dev/null
        # echo "SENTINEL not exit $sentinel_name"
fi
echo "SENTINEL=$sentinel_name" > /data/.sentinel
echo "CUSTOMER=$customer_name" >> /data/.sentinel
echo "HOSTIP=$sentinel_IP" >> /data/.sentinel
echo "GATEWAYURLS=$gateway_urls" >> /data/.sentinel
echo "GATEWAYURL=$gateway_url" >> /data/.sentinel
echo "API_URL=$rest_api_url" >> /data/.sentinel
echo "DOCKERHUB=$privatehub" >> /data/.sentinel`
```

So someone please help me on this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to run such a script from your docker - you can use ConfigMap/Secret.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-script-config
data:
  my-script.sh: |
    #!/bin/sh
    echo "Hi there - runing my-script..."
    cat /etc/hosts
    echo "Thats it! thats all my script"
```

Then you can inject that ConfigMap to your Pods using volumes (Here I used Deployment but it is similar for DaemonSet):

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-redis
          image: navivi/my-redis
          volumeMounts:
          - name: my-config # Must be the same as the volume name bellow
            mountPath: /opt/my-container/config
      volumes:
      - name: my-config
        configMap:
          name: my-script-config # The name of the ConfigMap
          defaultMode: 0777      # We need execution mode for the file
```

A file with the name my-script.sh will be placed in your container in the path you specified in the VolumeMounts.

But the file will be only placed in the container - inorder to execute it the container will have to have the logic to do it.
You can do it in a docker entrypoint file. For example, here I re-build the latest redis image as follow:

Dockerfile

```
FROM redis

RUN sed -i '/exec "\$@"/i /opt/my-container/config/my-script.sh' /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Basically - I inserted a line, to the real docker-entrypoint.sh of the image. Before it starts the redis server - run my-script.sh
Now, my-script.sh is not part of the image! So in an environment without the ConfigMap - that container will fail to start. There can be many ways you can define the new Dockerfile - to run your script. But you don't need to rebuild the image every time you want to change the script - as it is not part of the image.

Now, the tests:

- Created the ConfigMap and then the Deployment
- Checked the the logs of the pod and got:

```
Hi there - runing my-script...
.
.
Thats it! thats all my script
1:C 22 Jun 15:52:54.999 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
.
.
```

- I updated the ConfigMap - changed the script
- Deleted the pod, new pod created with the logs:

```
Hi there - I just changed  my-script...
.
.
Thats it! thats all my script
1:C 22 Jun 15:59:10.850 # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
.
.
```

Comment: I wrote the ConfigMap and tested it. I took the script as given in the question. I can make it shorten.

Comment: Thanks for the help...i tried that as you mentioned it took the script however it is not executing within the container....could you guide me on this point how to execute the script on that container will be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to run some script given in the configuration, the way I think to do it is by re-build your image. Add to the docker-entrypoint.sh a command that execute your script. This way it will be executed right before your container start. But looking at your script - are you sure you want to do it? Run a docker in your docker? There can be a better way to do it. Like running init-container in your pod.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, i don't want to re-build the image to include the script in the entry point of docker because this config files is always changeable...so i tried INIT containers concept but that is not working either...can you try the init concept and let me know may be i am not doing it correctly with init containers

Comment: You don't need to include the script in the image. Just execute the script in the docker-entrypoint.sh. Once the docker-entrypoint is running the script will already place there by the configuration. Just add the line `/bin/bash /path/to/script` to the docker-entrypoint.sh. You might need to chmod the script first.

Comment: i dont understand the concept here...what if i want to spin up a newer image/rolling updates....will the script will be executed along with it or i need to again mention the /bin/bash /path/to/script to the docker-entrypoint.sh

Comment: You need to add the line that execute the script only once and build a new image. Now whenever the container start the script will be executed. You can change the script by changing the configuration - but you don't need to change the image anymore. Just once.

Comment: I don't clearly understand...could you please grab the codes and image, try to reproduce the same and send me the steps clearly as you mentioned it before for the Config map and Daemonset will be much appreciated....i don't want to rush you, take your time do the testing on your machine and let me know the final piece

Comment: I edited the answer. I reproduce the same. I used `redis:latest` image which I re-build to `navivi/my-redis`. I used Deployment instead DaemonSet but it is the same. I hope it was more clear this time.

Comment: chmod: cannot access 'my-script.sh': No such file or directory
chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/my-container/config/..data/my-script.sh': Read-only file system

Comment: i am getting the following error when i tried to execute the deployment

Comment: chmod: cannot access 'my-script.sh': No such file or directory
chmod: changing permissions of '/opt/my-container/config/..data/my-script.sh': Read-only file system

Comment: If the user of your image is not root - then you might have permission issues. Try to place your script not in /opt/... But in a directory where the user has permissions

Comment: i provided the file permission but it is not over riding the entrypoint rather it executes after the image creations and getting the following error: Initializing Sentinel image...../opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh: line 31: docker: command not found /opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh: line 34: dmidecode: command not found /opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh: line 44: docker:

Comment: cp: cannot stat '/sentineld': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/data/sentineld': No such file or directory
/opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh: line 90: ip: command not found
/opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh: line 95: docker: command not found
/opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh: line 97: docker: command not found

Comment: Where did you place the script? mountPath? what is `/opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh` in your logs? It doesn't look right.

Comment: when i did a pwd in my script.sh inside the container image that gives the mountpath as follows: /opt/my-container/config - ignore this "/opt/nifi/bin/config/..data/my-script.sh" as i did some R&D to eliminate the errors

Comment: one more thing i want to know "is there a way without editing the Dockerfile of that image" because i don't know from where to get the Dockerfile however i have access only to the image

Comment: Hi Nesia,  Any update on the above comments?

Comment: I don't have any updates. I added an example above of how to run the script from the docker-entrypoint.sh. If you get No such file or directory - then I can guess you didn't place the script there. I guess you can debug it by first not changing the image at all. Just place the script via ConfigMap and then try to see if you can manually run it using `kubectl exec -it <your-pod> -- bin/sh <path to you script>`

Comment: Yes thanks for your help...as you mentioned i ran the script inside the pod but it says the following error message: [root@k8s-master ~]# kubectl exec -it my-deploy-85bcd96f44-7dlcs -- bin/sh /opt/my-container/config/my-script.sh
/opt/my-container/config/my-script.sh: line 1: line 29: docker: command not found
Initializing Sentinel image.....
/opt/my-container/config/my-script.sh: line 33: docker: command not found

Comment: My situation is explained here in detail: i have 1 master node & 2 WN all are installed with Kubernetes and docker...when i try to do a deployment using the docker image it deploys the image on the WN's however the configuration changes which are mounted as script on the container image is not executed within the pod instead it rolls on top of the container which doesn't have docker installed that is why i am getting "command not found" error...the script should run outside the image as this is the config. changes of the image. Hope i have explained the situation detail so that you can help me

Comment: If you tried to run the script and you got those errors - then that script cannot run in your container. There is something wrong in your solution. Your solution cannot be running a script taken from configuration as this question is decribed.

Comment: i dont understand your last comment could you be more elaborate on that please...